# Python reading a file switch from glob to os

Tags: python

so I am done making a program that searches all the .txt files from a directory

I am further storing each words from those files into a list.

I was wondering if I can use import os to achieve the same goal.

Here's my working code with import glob

```
import glob

path = 'C:/Users/folder/PycharmProjects/firstproject/*.txt'

files = glob.glob(path)

for name in files:
        with open(name, "r") as word_list:
             words = word_list.read().split()
```

Comment: Try `files = [f for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/folder/PycharmProjects/firstproject/') if f.endswith('.txt')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up:

```
import os
from os.path import join

path = 'C:/Users/folder/PycharmProjects/firstproject/'

files = [join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

for name in files:
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(name, "r") as word_list:
             words = word_list.read().split()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ! its perfect. Does the same thing but with os.